# Flip Every Nth Coin in R

Tags: r

My friend gave me a brain teaser that I wanted to try on R.

Imagine 100 coins in a row, with heads facing up for all coins.  Now every 2nd coin is flipped (thus becoming tails).  Then every 3rd coin is flipped.  How many coins are now showing heads?

To create the vector, I started with:

```
flips <- rep('h', 100)
levels(flips) <- c("h", "t")
```

Not sure how to proceed from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
coins <- rep(1, 100) # 1 = Head, 0 = Tail
n = 3 # run till the time when you flip every 3rd coin
invisible(sapply(2:n function(i) {indices <- seq(i, 100, i); coins[indices] <<- (coins[indices] + 1) %% 2}) )
which(coins == 1)
# [1]  1  5  6  7 11 12 13 17 18 19 23 24 25 29 30 31 35 36 37 41 42 43 47 48 49 53 54 55 59 60 61 65 66 67 71 72 73 77 78 79 83 84 85 89 90 91 95 96 97
sum(coins==1)
#[1] 49
```

If you run till n = 100, only the coins at the positions which are perfect squares will be showing heads.

```
coins <- rep(1, 100) # 1 = Head, 0 = Tail
n <- 100
invisible(sapply(2:n, function(i) {indices <- seq(i, 100, i); coins[indices] <<- (coins[indices] + 1) %% 2}) )
which(coins == 1)
#  [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
sum(coins==1)
# [1] 10
```